# Automated commits with Jenkins

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, openshift, cicd

Following scenario: a cicd pipeline at an openshift account where I have very limited accesses (just logging outputs, secrets and redeploy). I used to build my images in Jenkins, where I had the "build periodically" option. I work with an upper abstraction layer , built upon redhat openshift, that contains its own pipeline to build images but not an "scheduled / automated build function", hence I have to redeploy my 40+ microservices periodically so that I can keep the pods clear of vulnerabilities. A huge piece of manual work...

I don't plan to move my image building back to Jenkins, but I was wondering if is it possible to , for instance, using Jenkins to check in my git repositories and generate some automated commit of sorts (like a readme file update), which in turn would trigger a build automatically at my openshift cluster.

Might sound like a crazy idea but , has anyone ever came across a similar scenario? Could it be doable? I have both Jenkins and TravisCI avaliable for my project.

I tried thinking how a cronjob of sorts would help me getting this done, but since to my limited OC access scope, I don't think I would be able to even create a cron.

Comment: Jenkins can run scheduled jobs, and the Jenkins pipeline can run arbitrary shell commands, so nothing stops you from committing changes on a schedule.  There's a style of DevOps management called "GitOps" where most changes are indirectly triggered via source-control commits and you might look into that pattern, even if this is for your application and not infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you. I started configuring a Jenkins freestyle job run a few she'll commands. Currently trying to figure out why I get my Jenkins user credentials denied in GitHub. But you pointed me the right path